# Об употреблении слов "либо", "а", "не"

Tags: семантика

Предположим на столике лежат туз, король, дама и валет.

Верно ли, что:

- указание "Возьми либо туза, либо короля, либо туза." означает указание "Возьми короля, а не туза."?
- указание "Не бери туза, а возьми либо короля, либо даму, либо валета." означает указание "Либо возьми короля, а не туза, либо возьми даму, а не туза, либо возьми валета, а не туза."?

Answer (score 1):

Правильно:   1) "Возьми либо туза, либо короля, либо туза." - Возьми или *короля,* или *туза.* Союз либо -либо как и союз или -или предполагает выбор. Второе предложение с точки смысла верное. Но! Стилистически небезупречное. Можно сформулировать так:  возьми либо короля, либо даму, либо валета, а не туза. У вас при каждом слове повторяется слово "туз"с отрицанием:  ненужных повторов вообще стоит избегать.

Comment: Спасибо за замечания. Я обдумаю их.